# Database relationships in sequelize

Tags: sql, database, sequelize.js, relationship

I'm new to database and i'm trying to implement relationships between tables.

I have two tables in my sql database which are **equipment** and **equipmentType**.

An equipment has only one equipmentType and there are lots of equipmentsTypes. But an equipmentType can be used in multiple equipments.

I'm in doubt if this is a one-to-one or one-to-many relationship.
And how would I associate it with Sequelize.

Comment: The relationship between equipmentType and equipment is one-to-many since One equipmentType can be used by more than one equipment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Equipment` and `EquipmentType` is N:1 relationship. So it would look like this in Sequelize:

```js
Equipment.belongsTo(EquipmentType)
EquipmentType.hasMany(Equipment)
```